# Reagent Component not Re-Rendering on Prop Change

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

My Reagent component ist a simple div that has a `component-did-mount` and a `component-did-update` hook. It draws notes using vexflow.

```clj
(defn note-bar [notes]
  (reagent/create-class
    {:display-name         "Note Bar"
     :reagent-render       (fn [notes]
                             ^{:key notes}                  ;; force update
                             [:div#note-bar])
     :component-did-mount  (fn [this]
                             (draw-system-with-chord notes))
     :component-did-update (fn [this]
                             (draw-system-with-chord notes))}))
```

It is used like this.

```clj
(defn exercise-one []
  (let [note (re-frame/subscribe [:exercise-one/note])]
    [:div
     [note-bar/note-bar @note]
     [other]
     [components]]))
```

My event code is the following.

```clj
(defn store-exercise-one-note [db [_ note]]
  (assoc-in db [:exercise-one :note-bar :note] note))

(re-frame/reg-event-db
  :exercise-one/store-note
  store-exercise-one-note)

(defn query-exercise-one-note [db]
  (or (get-in db [:exercise-one :note-bar :note])
      [{:octave 4 :key :c}]))

(re-frame/reg-sub
  :exercise-one/note
  query-exercise-one-note)
```

I verified that the app-db value changes using 10x. Yet the note bar only displays a different note when Hot Reloading kicks in. I believe this is due to the `component-did-update` hook not being called.

My question is, is this the right way to bind a JavaScript library that renders something? If so, why does my component not update?

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed the component. See the documentation about form-3 components [here](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md)

```clj
(defn note-bar [notes]
  (reagent/create-class
    {:display-name         "Note Bar"
     :reagent-render       (fn [notes]
                             ^{:key notes}                  ;; force update
                             [:div#note-bar])
     :component-did-mount  (fn []
                             (draw-system-with-chord notes))
     :component-did-update (fn [this]
                             (let [new-notes (rest (reagent/argv this))]
                               (apply draw-system-with-chord new-notes)))}))
```